# PHP Microsoft Azure oauth2 token POST method not working

Tags: php, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, http-post

This is driving me nuts!

If the method is POST, why Azure is returning an "AADSTS90056: This endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request" error?

Code:

```
$url='http://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
 $data = array('code'=>$code,'resource'=>$resource,'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri, 'client_id' => $client_ID, 'scope' => $scope, 'grant_type' => $grant_type, 'client_secret' => $client_secret);

 $options = array(
     'http' => array(
         'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
         'method'  => 'POST',
         'content' => http_build_query($data)
     )
 );
 $context  = stream_context_create($options);
 $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

 var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Could you check your network calls to see if the request being sent is actually a POST?

Answer (score 1):

Azure OAuth 2.0 endpoint is only accessible via HTTPS and that HTTPS is enforced via a 302 redirect if we make a request to it with plain HTTP. This will cause the HTTP verb to change to GET. So, you'll need to use HTTPS instead of HTTP to make it work.

[image]